# multiple data lines for each person in my set

Tags: python, database, pivot-table

So basically, I have a data set that looks similar to this:

**Person|Class|Score**

David, Comp sci, A
David, English, B
David, Chemistry, A
Laura, Chemistry, A
Henry, English, D
Henry, French, A
Henry, Art, B
Clara, Comp Sci, B
Clara, English, A

So the idea here is that I put in my own set, for example,
Me:
  Chemistry, B
    English, A
Comp Sci, B

If you look at the data set, you will see that my classes are most similar to David. I want my program to sort the names from most to least similar. Except in this case, David is NOT the most similar. It will actually be Clara. Here is the idea: Clara has two classes that are exactly the same as my classes. David has all the same classes, but his grades are only slightly off to mine. So, I won't worry about the math of getting to that, since the idea of whether a person's grade is more relevant or the number of classes is.

So here is my question: how would I organize something like this in python for machine learning? I would know what to do if there was one name for each line, but in this case a person can take multiple classes. These multiple occurrences are **not** independent events. The thing I have in mind is that I want the program to give weight to given students based on their similarity to me. For example, I could say that "Because Clara has more similarity to me, when I order a pizza, her telling me she wants pepperoni is more likely to have me order pepperoni than anything that Henry suggests, since Henry doesn't have similar taste to me in anything. However, if she likes pepperoni but I absolutely hate pepperoni (or everyone else hates pepperoni), then I will completely ignore her request.". So, I am adding a weighted "score" per se based on their similarity.

I have two additional questions: How would I deal with a set of keywords for people? for example, for things learned in each class, I could say "David, comp sci, A, (time complexity, binary trees, if statements)". I would want to use this to find which class best matches these keywords. So, if I ask what has binary trees and time complexity, the program would spit out computer science based on everyone's keywords for it.
The other question is, what algorithm would work best? It seems to me that decision trees would work best in my case, but I am not sure.

Comment: If you haven't, check out this blog post: http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/. It has some good recommends such as scipy to use in Python to get started with machine learning.

Comment: Just a cursory reading makes me think you can simply count the shared classes and the highest score is the most similar. You could even weigh it based on grade closeness. For instance, for shared classes, you give letter grades an integer score, and find the difference, the lower the difference, the more weight that similar class is given. My first intuition is you're trying to over-engineer this. I don't think you need ML. Keywords can be handled similarly, if you just count the number of similar keywords it can weigh in on the total value of that class. Finding keywords is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic implementation demonstrating what I said in my comment. I leave keywords, parsing results, and extending as an exercise to you, ask any questions you want and I will amend this post with any details.

You can do exactly the same with the keywords and if you'd like to preserve them or the classes, that is doable. The further usage of the results MAY make use of ML, but my intuition says there are still simpler methods there too.

Also, determining the exact value that classes should be and grades is another task. This can heavily influence the results. As you're deciding whether classes or grades are more important...This will heavily depend on usage case, you could even have "bias slider" to change it as you need.

Here is a fairly robust scoring function:

`scores[name] += (2*(2-bias)) - (bias * abs(data_point[1] - pivot_point[1]))`

```
import numpy as np

people = """David, Comp Sci, A
David, English, B
David, Chemistry, A
Laura, Chemistry, A
Henry, English, D
Henry, French, A
Henry, Art, B
Clara, Comp Sci, B
Clara, English, A
OrbDeceptionist, Chemistry, B
OrbDeceptionist, English, A
OrbDeceptionist, Comp Sci, B"""


def get_names(dataset):
    names = []

    for line in dataset.split('\n'):
        name = line.split(',')[0]
        if name not in names:
            names.append(name)

    return names


grade_table = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'F': 4}
def get_classes(dataset, person):
    classes = []

    for line in dataset.split('\n'):
        name, subject, grade = line.split(',')
        if name == person:
            classes.append((subject, grade_table[grade.strip(' ')]))

    return classes


def most_similar(dataset, pivot, bias=0.3):
    pivot_data = get_classes(dataset, pivot)

    scores = {}

    names = get_names(dataset)

    for name in names:
        person_data = get_classes(dataset, name)

        for pivot_point in pivot_data:
            for data_point in person_data:
                if data_point[0] == pivot_point[0]:
                    if name not in scores:
                        scores[name] = 0

                    scores[name] += (2*(2-bias)) - (bias * abs(data_point[1] - pivot_point[1]))

    scores.pop(pivot)
    # You don't want to round in your final version, this is just to make it cleaner to see for the example.
    for k, v in scores.items():
        scores[k] = round(v)

    return scores


print('High bias favors grades, low bias favors classes.')
for b in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
    print('bias:', b, "|", most_similar(people, "OrbDeceptionist", b))
```

Results:

```
High bias favors grades, low bias favors classes.
bias: 0.0 | {'Henry': 4.0, 'Laura': 4.0, 'Clara': 8.0, 'David': 12.0}
bias: 0.1 | {'Henry': 4.0, 'Laura': 4.0, 'Clara': 8.0, 'David': 11.0}
bias: 0.2 | {'Henry': 3.0, 'Laura': 3.0, 'Clara': 7.0, 'David': 10.0}
bias: 0.3 | {'Henry': 2.0, 'Laura': 3.0, 'Clara': 7.0, 'David': 9.0}
bias: 0.4 | {'Henry': 2.0, 'Laura': 3.0, 'Clara': 6.0, 'David': 8.0}
bias: 0.5 | {'Henry': 2.0, 'Laura': 2.0, 'Clara': 6.0, 'David': 8.0}
bias: 0.6 | {'Henry': 1.0, 'Laura': 2.0, 'Clara': 6.0, 'David': 7.0}
bias: 0.7 | {'Henry': 0.0, 'Laura': 2.0, 'Clara': 5.0, 'David': 6.0}
bias: 0.8 | {'Henry': -0.0, 'Laura': 2.0, 'Clara': 5.0, 'David': 5.0}
bias: 0.9 | {'Henry': -0.0, 'Laura': 1.0, 'Clara': 4.0, 'David': 4.0}
bias: 1.0 | {'Henry': -1.0, 'Laura': 1.0, 'Clara': 4.0, 'David': 3.0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually didn't think anyone would write this out into a program!

Comment: Can I ask how you implement the bias slider? I am doing this program as a personal project to hopefully develop a really unique software. I plan on running many simulations of data sets in order to find what works. Unfortunately I am still pretty new to programming, still studying in college at the moment.

Comment: Okay, my way of going at it would probably be to have a value like bias=0.0 as a parameter. 0.0 would tend towards classes, while 1.0 towards grades. In order to implement it, you can do something like this where the scores calculation is replaced with: `scores[name] += (2*(1-bias)) - (bias*abs(data_point[1] - pivot_point[1]))` That would result in the class value being max when `bias=0.0` and grades would be full value when `bias=1.0` The important thing is that you do not modify bias when operating on the same "test", but when you're doing new ones maybe you'll find a bias better for each.

Comment: In this case, I muddled with the scores just enough to make grades more important than classes, but really, classes are probably more indicative...And grades...so I would think somewhere around `bias=0.3` would be good. P.S. The most important thing is to just keep coding. You'll write bad code, fail, and improve it. Don't put all the emphasis on the end goal, the journey is just as important and small projects are important to learn from.

Comment: Thanks again, you are the kind of person I hope to be like in my journey :)